# scope of `this` changing on a production server?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following three functions in a Backbone View. Originally, the call to `updateTimer` within `Playback` and `StartRecording` functions triggered an error, which went away after I preceded the call with `this`, as in  `this.updateTimer`. However, I've now put a demo app on a production server (where the code is compiled into one file) and the call to this.updateTimer is triggering an error

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'updateTimer' (repeated 28 times)
```

Can you explain why this might be?

The three functions working on my local machine:

```
     PlayBack: function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
        this.updateTimer(0);
        SC.recordPlay({
            progress: function(ms) {
                this.updateTimer(ms);
            }
        });

      },

      updateTimer: function(ms){
         $('.status').text(SC.Helper.millisecondsToHMS(ms));


      },

      StartRecording: function(e){

         $('#startRecording').hide();
          $('#stopRecording').show();
          e.preventDefault();
          SC.record({
            progress: function(ms, avgPeak) {
              this.updateTimer(ms);
            }
          });

      },
```

From the console of the production server

```
,PlayBack: function(t) {
        t.preventDefault(), this.updateTimer(0), SC.recordPlay({progress: function(t) {
                this.updateTimer(t)
            }})
    },updateTimer: function(t) {
        $(".status").text(SC.Helper.millisecondsToHMS(t))
    },StartRecording: function(t) {
        $("#startRecording").hide(), $("#stopRecording").show(), t.preventDefault(), SC.record({progress: function(t) {
                this.updateTimer(t)
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'updateTimer' (repeated 28 times)
            }})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) context is lost in the inner function you are passing to `SC.record` and no longer refers to your Backbone view.  There a few ways around this, one of which is to take advantage of closures and create a reference to the correct `this` and use it in the `progress` callback:

```
  StartRecording: function(e){
     var self = this;
     $('#startRecording').hide();
      $('#stopRecording').show();
      e.preventDefault();
      SC.record({
        progress: function(ms, avgPeak) {
          self.updateTimer(ms);
        }
      });

  },
```

Same thing goes for the call to `updateTimer` in the call to `SC.recordPlay` in `Playback`.

Comment: thanks, I should have known that, but why woudn't the error get triggered on my local machine?

Comment: @Leahcim: That code really shouldn't work on the local machine either.  Perhaps the error went unnoticed, or that code wasn't triggered for some reason?